# Calling update() doesn't trigger paintEvent()

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, paintevent

I am trying to draw a line at the center of a widget, so I tried to call `paintEvent()` by using `update()`.

However, `paintEvent()` does not get called. Why is that?

test_paint.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_PAINT_H
#define TEST_PAINT_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QWidget>

class test_paint:public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    test_paint(QWidget* device){paper = device;}

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e){
        QPainter p(paper);
        QPen myPen;
        myPen.setColor(Qt::red);
        myPen.setWidth(5);
        p.setPen(myPen);
        QPoint p1;
        QPoint p2;
        p1.setX(10);
        p1.setY(10);
        p2.setX(100);
        p2.setY(10);
        p.drawLine(p1,p2);
    };
    void try_painting(){
        update();
    }
public slots:
    void call_paint(){
        try_painting();
    }

private:
    QWidget* paper;
};

#endif // TEST_PAINT_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QObject>
#include "test_paint.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc,argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    window.setFixedSize(500, 600);

    QMenu menu("Menu");
    window.menuBar()->addMenu("Menu");

    QWidget *center = new QWidget();
    window.setCentralWidget(center);
    window.show();

    QPushButton* push = new QPushButton("test_move");
    QVBoxLayout* vlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    vlayout -> addWidget(push);
    center->setLayout(vlayout);

    test_paint* d = new test_paint(center);

    QObject::connect(push,SIGNAL(clicked()),d,SLOT(call_paint()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You can't use the `paintEvent` method of one widget (`test_paint` in this case) to directly draw on another widget (member `paper` here).  You should probably be seeing all sorts of warning messages if you are running this from a terminal/console.

Comment: @G.M. technically you can, but should call QWidget::render() with painter as argument.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, good point (I should know better than to use phrases like 'you can't' on SO :-).  Having said that, calling `QWidget::render()` still, as far as I'm aware, requires that the target widget has an overridden `paintEvent` method that contains the code currently in the OP's `test_paint::paintEvent` implementation.

Comment: @G.M. an intersting point I'm not sure of. I might find time to test. My understanding that main mistake was `p(paper)` and not using client area geometry. Passing painter up and don't should have purpose of combined rendering with children, but then `paper` should be a child and it apears it isn't

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 problems with your approach:

### Initializing the custom widget:

You have this:

```cpp
QWidget *center = new QWidget();

window.setCentralWidget(center);
window.show();

QPushButton* push = new QPushButton("test_move");
QVBoxLayout* vlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
vlayout -> addWidget(push);
center->setLayout(vlayout);

test_paint* d = new test_paint(center);
```

Where you initialize `d` with `center` as its parent, and you do not include it in any layout. And that is after you make `window` (`center`'s parent) visible, which is a problem because a parent widget will only make its children visible if added before it itself is made visible (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77243836/17726418) on [How to make a child widget added in a slot visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241583/how-to-make-a-child-widget-added-in-a-slot-visible/77243836#77243836)).

To fix that, you could either move the initialization before the parent's `show`:

```cpp
QWidget *center = new QWidget();

window.setCentralWidget(center);

test_paint* d = new test_paint(center);

window.show();

QPushButton* push = new QPushButton("test_move");
QVBoxLayout* vlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
vlayout -> addWidget(push);
center->setLayout(vlayout);
```

Or, you could call `d.show();`.

However, this still won't work:

- If you use the first solution, you still won't get anything visible.
- If you go with the second, `d` will become a second window.

And that is because of the second problem:

### Constructor:

You have the below as your constructor:

```cpp
test_paint(QWidget* device) { paper = device; }
```

Which does not [initialize the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor) with the parent widget that you pass as `device`, thus not enabling you to benefit from parent/child relations between widgets.

This leads to improper events handling and propagation, and ultimately `paintEvent` not getting triggered, or causing a second window, all of which is mentioned in [QWidget Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#details):

> `QWidget *parent = nullptr` is the parent of the new widget. If it is `nullptr` (the default), the new widget will be a window. If not, it will be a child of parent, and be constrained by parent's geometry (unless you specify Qt::Window as window flag).

So you fix that as follows:

```cpp
test_paint(QWidget* device) : QWidget(device) { paper = device; }
  base class initialization ->^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And again, this will turn up another problem:

### Trying to draw a widget outside its paint event:

In `test_paint::paintEvent`, you have this:

```cpp
QPainter p(paper);
```

Which means you want to draw/draw in top of `paper`, however the current `paintEvent` is that of `d`, not `paper`, that will cause you the following warnings:

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
```

To fix that, you should use the current widget and draw on it:

```cpp
QPainter p(this);
```

---

Here's a simplified, minimal example:

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class test_paint : public QWidget
{
public:
    test_paint(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) {}

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e) override
    {
        qDebug()<<"painting"<<size();
        QPainter p(this);

        p.fillRect(rect(), Qt::white);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;
    test_paint d(&w);
    QPushButton push("test");
    QVBoxLayout vlayout;

    vlayout.addWidget(&push);
    w.setLayout(&vlayout);

    QObject::connect(&push, &QPushButton::clicked, [&d]()
    {
        qDebug()<<"updating";
        d.update();
    });

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of a window with a button "test" and a white rectangle]

Some of the output:

```
painting QSize(100, 30)
painting QSize(100, 30)
painting QSize(100, 30)
updating
painting QSize(100, 30)
painting QSize(100, 30)
painting QSize(100, 30)
updating
painting QSize(100, 30)
painting QSize(100, 30)
painting QSize(100, 30)
```