# How to add and remove new widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple Qt6 project created in Qt Creator. This is a window with just one button. I want this button to disappear and a text (in a QLabel) to appear when the button is clicked.

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::pressed, this, &MainWindow::generate);
}

void MainWindow::generate() {
    delete ui->pushButton;
    QLabel* a = new QLabel("Text", ui->centralwidget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

When I press the button, it disappears, but the text doesn't appear.

When I move:

```
QLabel* a = new QLabel("Text", ui->centralwidget);
```

to the constructor, after `ui->setupUi(this);` line, the text appears.

Why doesn't it appear after pressing the button? How to fix it?

Comment: At a minimum you will need to call show() on your newly-created QLabel.  You’ll probably also want to addWidget() it to the appropriate QLayout, or at least call setGeometry() on it, to get it positioned where you want it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, I will try call show(). But in this case, why I don't need to call it in constructor?

Comment: The constructor executes before show() is called on the MainWindow object, and show() affects the children of the object  it is called on, so pushButton gets made implicitly visible by that call.

Comment: I can't flag this as a duplicate because it does not have an upvoted neither an accepted answer, but see if it answers your question: [How to make a child widget added in a slot visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241583/how-to-make-a-child-widget-added-in-a-slot-visible/77243836#77243836). There's also this related question: [Calling update() doesn't trigger paintEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77608433/calling-update-doesnt-trigger-paintevent/77609305#77609305), it's not a direct duplicate, so I don't feel comfortable enough using it as such. I answered both of them.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you have a parent widget with layout, which then takes care of the placement and dimensions of the child widgets. So this function would become

```
void MainWindow::generate() {
    delete ui->pushButton;
    QLabel* a = new QLabel("Text");
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(a);
}
```

In this code it is required that `centralWidget` has a layout. If it doesn't, give it one in the Designer.

When adding widget to layout, layout will automatically make it visible. If you didn't use layout, then you'd need to `show()` it explicitly, but do use layout unless you have a specific reason to not to.

---

I suggest you study QWidgets and Qt layouts: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/layout.html

Also look inside the generated ui_*.h file to see what kind of code is actually generated to create the UI, and try to understand it a bit.

Comment: If I may, the explanation is a bit ambiguous, as it's not really clear to what "here" in "explicit show is required" refers, also because the `a->show()` in the snippets is actually unnecessary (a new widget added to a layout becomes implicitly visible as long as the layout-managed parent is/becomes visible).

Comment: @musicamante Fixed and improved.